# Why don't I see "'At First" and "At last" options after pressing alt + m in the blender 2.78b

Tags: vertices, edges

[image]

Can anyone please help me out to identify why I don't see At First or At last option for merging the vertices. This is my first POC with blender cube mesh.

In the image, you can see that I have selected the vertices against the black color edge.

Comment: Because there is no first or last... that can happen when you select all then deselect some. Try selecting manually with shift or ctrl.

Comment: Thanks @lemon, it worked. Maybe this is silly question but I am just beginner so I was pulling my hairs for it. :-)

Comment: The only silly questions are these which are never asked ; )